# Максимально возможный размер очереди тасков для ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, многопоточность

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос - есть какое-то ограничение на размер очереди тасков в `ThreadPoolExecutor`? Если есть, то что будет происходить если submit в пул, будет вызываться уже после достижения максимального размера очереди?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет ограничения, если вы сами не поставите в него очередь ограниченного размера (можно сделать через конструктор). И да, OOM можно получить в теории, если такси накопятся в очереди и очередь распухнет и займёт всю память. Разумеется, при это падать будет всё и вся.

Answer (score -1):

В очереди будет стоять, так же, как и если бы не было пула вообще.

Comment: То есть ограничения нет ? можно сабмитить до OOM эксепшенов ?

Comment: у тебя что настолько "тяжёлые" потоки? ThreadPoolService - занимается их работой, и в твоем случае, лучше обрабатывать OOM  ошибки, да и вообще лучше кругом их обрабатывать и логировать

Comment: Вопрос не с том, насколько тяжелые у меня потоки, а в том, что будет, если я тупо в цикле начну сабмитить таски в пул с 1 потоком, причем сабмититься они будут быстрее, чем выполнятся. Что произойдет тогда?

Comment: запутал ты меня,, смотри потоков ты можешь сабмитеть сколько хочешь, они просто будут ждать очереди выполнения, а ООМ может вызвать твоя

Comment: Стоп,вы неправильно поняли все. Я ведь сабмичу не потоки, а таски, которые помещаюся в очередь. Размер этой очереди меня и интересует. А все эти таски выполняются в 1 потоке, тк пул , в который идет сабмит содержит 1 поток.

Comment: ну да, я просто сказал, что тут логика простая, если хватает места в памяти для выполнения объекта - он выполнится, если нет - будет ООМ, тут не в потоках дело, иногда можно увеличить себе место в JVM

Comment: возможно, проще будет разобраться на конкретном примере.

1. у нас есть один поток и мы сабмитим много тасков, которые засыпают на некоторое время, они будут выполнятся по мере предоставления им процессорного времени диспетчером задач, при этом оом не будет, так как они просто "засыпают".

2. тот же случай, только таски тяжёлые и перемножают большие матрици, потоки будут также в очереди, будут выполнятся по одному, ошибка оом возможно, при больших размерах матриц, но так как они в одном потоке и так как при других условиях матрица все же перемножается, программа должна работать корректно